Why does the background colour bleed around the top and bottom left corners of an image in AsyncImage?
I have the following code:
   @Composable
fun TestCard(
    descriptionText: String,
    imageContentDescription: String,
    textColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    elevation: Dp = 1.dp,
    imageUri: String? = null
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(74.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
        elevation = elevation

    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight() // Ensure it takes up full height
                    .weight(0.25f)  // Take 25% of the width
            ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    model = imageUri,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds, // Ensures the image crops to fill bounds
                    contentDescription = imageContentDescription,
                    placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.blue_image),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()  // Fills the Box completely
                )
            }
            Text(
                text = descriptionText,
                color = textColor,
                fontSize = FontSize.Medium,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                maxLines = 3,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = Dimensions.Medium)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .weight(0.75f)
            )
        }
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
    TestMaterialTheme {
        TestCard(
            descriptionText = "Description of the item",
            imageUri = null,
            imageContentDescription = "",
            textColor = MediumGrey
        )
    }
}

Zoomed in top left

Zoomed in bottom left

Why does the code above add some padding to the top left and bottom left, making the image not fully fill those areas?
I've tried adjusting the contentScale, but it hasn't worked.
Even switched to wrapping the AsyncImage in a Box

As you can see there is a red halo on the top and an bottom right
The sample image to use :


Do you mean the cutout caused by RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)? Or something that is already part of the image (which we cannot reproduce since we do not have the image)? Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean.

@Leviathan I have update the question and included the sample image

@George Are you talking about the small white space at the top and bottom left rounded corner? Now, you are writing As you can see there is a red halo on the top and an bottom right, but I don't see anything in the bottom and top right.

The only thing I notice that might be out of order in the second screenshot is a light red tint that mixes with the otherwise blue parts of the rounded corners. It's only distinguishable when magnified, looking at the pixels that form the border. That tint comes from the red background and vanishes when the background is set to blue (which shouldn't have any influence, though). Is that the issue you have?

@Leviathan  Yes, thats the issue, The red on the background should not be visible, if the whole image takes up the space. So My question is, why is the image not taking up the maxsize and letting the red bleed out in the top and bottom left corners.

That is probably caused by the antialiasing used to smooth the curve which gradually merges the foreground color with the background color. I haven't a solution ready for that. To improve chances of others answering you should [edit] the question and replace your code with a [mre] without the AsyncImage (a simple Box with a background of Color.Black inside a Box with a backgrond of Color.Red would be more clear). Also remove everything else that is not necessary. Make sure to upload a new screenshot magnified by 1000% or something similar so it is easy to see the red tint with the naked eye.

You should also choose a new title that better describes the issue.

Title for the question can be updated
